# Mysql Mac OS X how to NOT require password when on local machine

Tags: mysql, macos

On my linux server the host set it up so I can do `mysql -u root` and I am logged in. (I have a password, but on that server my password is stored somewhere (I think?).

How do I do this for mac os x so I don't have to type my password for `mysql` and `mysqldump`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.my.cnf` file in your home directory with the following format

```
[client]
user = root
password = root_password
```

Change the username to whatever is appropriate for your setup.